# Is there a reason to sanitize using (mysqli_real_escape_string) on my $_GET or $_POST variables when using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
```

**OR is this just ok?**

```
$name = $_GET["name"];

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // do something with $row
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'll end up double escaping things. Bound parameters are a replacement for manual escaping.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to. The preparation already does everything for you.